# generating music from neurosky headset using midi in c#

Tags: c#, midi

i am student of final year and have started working on my project.i have purchased the neurosky mindset,and was thinking to generatemusic by assigning one instrument to each wave(that are sent from the headset)e.g drum on alpha waves,using midi ,i want to to do the coding in c# im not a professional,so can any1 tell me if it is feasible?
and any links that will b helping

Comment: If you want to generate a tune just by thinking about the notes, why don't you just hum it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is entirely possible.  I have already done exactly what you are suggesting.  You can find [more details on my website for MindMaster MIDI](http://www.musatcha.com/software/MindMasterMIDI/).

There are a few parts to this.  The first is getting the samples from the headset and putting them in a buffer.  For that, you will need the [Neurosky SDK](http://store.neurosky.com/products/developer-tools-2-1).

Next, you will need to process those samples.  There are many algorithms for dealing with brain waves.  The easiest method (and the most fruitful, depending on who you ask), is convert your waveform from the time domain to the frequency domain, and check the relative levels of a few bands in the alpha/beta frequency range.  (This is anywhere from 8Hz to 24Hz or so.)

There are a handful of methods to do this programmatically.  [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) is a common way, and you will find many algorithms available.  I decided FFT was too slow for my purposes, and ended up using the [Goertzel algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm).  This was more efficient, as I am only looking at a few bands.

Once you have that, you need to write your application to turn that data into MIDI.  How you do this is up to you, and the features you wish to implement.

Next, you need to send MIDI data.  I'm not sure how familiar you are with MIDI, but at a basic level, there are note on/off messages.  You will likely be more interested in control-change messages, which control various parameters such as cutoff frequency and resonance.  To send MIDI with C#, again you have many choices.  [Leslie Sanford's example on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx) is sufficient to get you started.

Finally, if you have questions on any of this, you are better off asking individual questions separately.  Stack Overflow really isn't the place for "I want to do this big project, tell me how to do it all at once".

Comment: well im a little confused about how to put the midi data on the waves(i.e inpt/output of the data) ,like u said im pretty new with midi + the waves are already are assigned with frequencies?,,,,,and thanx a dozen:)

Comment: @peshoge, these are basic questions that are up to you to decide how to implement.  How you interpret the waves, and what you do with the data is an individual decision.  I've essentially given you your entire project... what more could you want?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I'm qualified to answer your question. I am developing a C# xna videogame right now.

```
public void _thinkGearWrapper_ThinkGearChanged(object sender, ThinkGearChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // update the textbox and sleep for a tiny bit
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
        {
            lblAttention.Text = "Attention: " + e.ThinkGearState.Attention;
            lblMeditation.Text = "Meditation: " + e.ThinkGearState.Meditation;
            attentionvar = e.ThinkGearState.Attention;
            meditationvar = e.ThinkGearState.Meditation;
            attentionstring = attentionvar.ToString();
            meditationstring = meditationvar.ToString();
            txtState.Text = e.ThinkGearState.ToString();
        }));
    Thread.Sleep(10);

  senddata();



}


public void senddata()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("\\programming\\meditationvariables.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    fs.Close();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("\\programming\\meditationvariables.txt", true, Encoding.ASCII);
    string nextline = meditationstring;
    sw.Write(nextline);
    sw.Close();
}
```

it's feasible. You need to download this project and look it over even though it's xna3.5
http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MindBlaster

and you need to go this website
 developer.neurosky.com

check out my dropbox for my project it'll help too not updated yet though the new updated version will be alot more helpful comes with a read me and everything

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4tkemk6py7ffvch/JESUSISGOD-MINDBALLalpha.zip

Answer (score 0):

The Android API exposes a data structure that would make your life a lot easier (not having to integrate with an FFT library or god forbid write your own).

In particular MSG_EEG_POWER.

From the SDK doc: 
"The eight EEG powers are: delta (0.5 - 2.75Hz), theta (3.5 - 6.75Hz), low-alpha (7.5 - 9.25Hz), high-alpha (10 - 11.75Hz), low-beta (13 - 16.75Hz), high-beta (18 - 29.75Hz), low-gamma (31 - 39.75Hz), and mid-gamma (41 - 49.75Hz)."

You can then feed those into some of the stuff that Brad is doing.  You may be able to talk to the Neurosky guys to see if they can give you an API for C#.